# uuid_binary form validation error: The choice does not exist or is not unique

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the [ramsey/uuid-doctrine](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid-doctrine) package to have binary UUIDs as primary key for an entity:

```
class Site
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid_binary")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

I need to build a form for another entity which has that entity in a ManyToOne relation.

So I added, in my form builder, an EntityType as follows:

```
$builder->add('site')
```

Everything works, the HTML select has the uuids as keys, but when I submit the form I get this validation error:

> Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[site] = 4a41b3c4-4299-11e6-b562-fc3fdb5f816d
>
> Caused by:
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
>   Unable to reverse value for property path "site": The choice "4a41b3c4-4299-11e6-b562-fc3fdb5f816d" does not exist or is not unique
>
> Caused by:
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
>   The choice "4a41b3c4-4299-11e6-b562-fc3fdb5f816d" does not exist or is not unique

---

If I do, in a controller:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
  ->getRepository('AppBundle:Site')->find('4a41b3c4-4299-11e6-b562-fc3fdb5f816d');
```

It does find the entity, so it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only hack I could find: I removed the field value from the request and manually set it later

```
$site_uuid = $_POST['smart_link']['site'] ?? null;

$request_link = $request->request->get('link');
$request_link['site'] = '';
$request->request->set('link', $request_link);

$form->handleRequest($request);

....

$link->setSite($em->getRepository('AppBundle:Site')->find($site_uuid));
```