# Symfony Forms EntityType Validation Error: Choice does not Exist with uuid-doctrine

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm using the ramsey/uuid-doctrine package to have binary UUIDs as primary key for an entity. The same problem was already posted a few months ago, but the accepted answer is just a hack. ([uuid_binary form validation error: The choice does not exist or is not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38205531/7473318))
I would like to find a long term solution:

```
class ReferencedEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid_binary")
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

I need to build a form for another entity which has above entity in a ManyToOne relation.

So I added, in my form builder, an EntityType as follows:

```
        ->add('status', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => '<FullyQualtifiedPath>\ReferencedEntity',
            'choice_label' => 'title',
            'label' => 'Status'
        ])
```

Everything works, the HTML select has the uuids as keys, but when I submit the form I get this validation error:

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[status] = 1f1fdca0-5bcd-11e7-b6d1-0a002700000b

Caused by: Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException Unable to reverse value for property path "status": The choice "1f1fdca0-5bcd-11e7-b6d1-0a002700000b" does not exist or is not unique

Caused by: Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException The choice "1f1fdca0-5bcd-11e7-b6d1-0a002700000b" does not exist or is not unique
```

If query the Doctrine Repository in the controller it finds the ReferencedEntity.

Comment: I would have commented on the previous question but haven't got enough reputation :/

Comment: Have you tried using the `query_builder` form option?